# Controlling power to many WS2812 LEDs in a battery-powered project

Tags: microcontroller, led, teensy

I am building an electronic board game which will have 500+ addressable LEDs in it - I don't know the exact model but they claim to be WS2812B, I bought them from Amazon here: [https://www.amazon.com/XUNATA-Integrated-Controller-WS2812B-1000pcs/dp/B071SM1F7G](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071SM1F7G).

When the game is running, I expect most of the LEDs to be off or low brightness, but these LEDs have a default of fully lit on power-up. So, before you send them data to turn them off, that many LEDs is going to draw 30A. I'm going to be driving them with a Teensy on the same supply and the whole thing will run off a LiPo battery.

My question is whether I should account for this in my design and how. My options are:

- Ignore it - just get a DC converter and battery that can handle the peak load and make sure the Teensy turns all the LEDs off first thing.
- Control both the power and data pins from the Teensy; I can divide the LEDs into segments which draw 2A at startup and flip them one at a time. Not sure if I should use low-side switching with NPN or high-side switching with PNP transistors
- ??? Is there a way to change the default maybe?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.  It may be on topic on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.